# Trying to use spring security with optional x509 client certificate

Tags: spring, security, x509certificate, option-type

I have a simple spring boot app with spring security for SSL and x509 client certificate.

I want to run it in dev-mode using just http and no client certificate.
And prod-mode using https and x509 certificate.

I have simple demo app that runs the secure site OK.
https://coling01@bitbucket.org/coling01/ssldemo.git

Hitting the secure site with certificate works OK
a) curl --cacert server.pem --cert client1.p12:changeit https://localhost:8443/demo

I want to be able to switch to insecure mode and hit it as
b) http on port80 without certificates
( I do have port 8080 running and it responds but hits an error trying to check client certificate which is not passed )

Any ideas ? I hoped there would be a simple switch to disable client-auth but cannot find this.

Comment: Please add [mcve]. Code samples should be in the question, not on external site.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Profiles as per [Mkyong's example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/).
With that you can create 2 different `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s,

First one for `dev` profile:

```
@Profile("dev")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class DevSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
  }
}
```

And 2nd one production ready and secured:

```
@Profile("prod")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ProductionSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .x509()
        .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!